# Angular2 reactive form not firing when onSubmit() function is triggered? ( But grabbing form with getElementById and calling form.submit() works)

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

Currently when I click on `<input type='submit' />`
It will submit the form with a POST request and redirects me to `mockURL`. Which is the behavior that I'm looking for.

**In xForm.html** :

```html
    <form 
        id="xForm"
        [formGroup]="xFormGroup" 
        method="POST"
        [action]="mockUrl"
        (ngSubmit)="submitXForm()"
        >
        <input formControlName="requireSecret" type="hidden" name="requireSecret"/>
        <input type="submit" value="sumbit"/>
    </form>
```

**In xForm.component.ts** :

```js
export class xFormComponent implements OnInit {
  public xFormGroup: FormGroup;
  public mockUrl: string = "https://www.mockURL.com"
  private secretFormValue: string = 'secret'

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeForm();
  }

  initializeForm(): void {
    this.xFormGroup = this.fb.group({
     requireSecret: secretFormValue
    })
  }

  public submitXForm(): void {
    console.log("clicked")

    const xform  = document.getElementById('xForm') as HTMLFormElement;
    xform.submit();
  }

}
```

*But What I'm having trouble is:*

How do I get this behavior the 'angular way' without using the form's nativeElement and calling form.submit()?
I tried a couple of things but I feel like I'm circling around and missing some key information.

Any help is much appreciated thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `method="POST"` and call the backend API directly with `HttpClient` from the `ngSubmit` handler

Angular prevents the default submit behavior of the `form` in favour of more explicit submit handling